# Recording the radio streaming of Radiotray or Rhythmbox

Tags: music, rhythmbox, streaming, internet-radio

I have checked the other questions before asking this one.

I am using radiotray for the streaming and wish to record the streams of di.fm.

I tried the trick with pulseaudio volume settings for recording and radiotray doesn't show up there. I am using 12.04 ubuntu.

Is there any way for recording from say rhythmbox with some plugin or radiotray with any other method?

Answer (score 4):

### Rhythmbox plugin

Yes - its certainly possible in 12.04.

I've been porting a few rhythmbox v0.x plugins to work with rhythmbox v2.9x - for example v2.96 used in 12.04 Ubuntu.

One GTK3 port is *Radio-Browser*

[image]

[image]

It is packaged in my rhythmbox PPA (link) below.

Alternatively, you can clone the GitHub repository and install:

#### how-to

```
sudo apt-get install git streamripper gir1.2-gconf-2.0
git clone https://github.com/fossfreedom/radio-browser
cd radio-browser
./install.sh
```

Finally, launch Rhythmbox, activate the global menu (move your mouse to the top of the screen) - *Edit - Plugins - Internet  Radio Station Browser*

Issues with this on GitHub not AskUbuntu or Launchpad - thanks.

---

Linked Questions:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)
- [Record a programs output with PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio)