# How to integrate Rhythmbox to play Internet Radio?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, internet-radio

I have been very fond of the sound menu integration that can be done via **Last.fm** and the present radio stations. I wanted to know a way to listen to **JazzRadio** or for that matter *any radio* on the Internet I like.

I tried installing the plug-in for Rhythmbox but it didn't show in the plug-ins (menu) for Internet radio in Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### searching for radio-stations

The default Rhythmbox URL based radio-station capability is limited - you have to research the internet radio-station - and then find what the actual URL it uses to play the radio-stream.

Fortunately - there is another way

*disclaimer - I'm the author of this plugin*

The RadioBrowser plugin could be useful if you like to browse for new radio stations.

You mentioned Jazz...

[image]

There are several jazz radio-stations as shown in the picture.

More information in the links below

**installation instructions**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-radio-browser
```

then start rhythmbox and select the menu *edit-plugins*, tick the checkbox *internet radio station browser*

---

Useful Links:

- [Recording the radio streaming of Radiotray or Rhythmbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170506/recording-the-radio-streaming-of-radiotray-or-rhythmbox/170559#170559)
- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins/147943#147943)

Answer (score 4):

Open Rythmbox, on the side panel, under library select Radio.
Then click on the Add button.

It will open a place for you to type the URL of the internet radio station you like.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 40.0.

1. Go to the webpage of your preferred radio station.
2. Right-click on any empty space of the webpage.
3. Select see information on this page.
4. Select Multimedia tab.
5. Look for streaming file and copy the path.
6. Open Rhythmbox, under Library select Radio.
7. Click the Add button. It will open a place for you to type the URL of the internet radio station you like.
8. Paste the path from step 5 and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that one can add Internet radio stations in bulk as well in Rhythmbox by using "Import File" feature. I have tried text or CSV files so far with success. The file has to have only one column of Internet radio station URLs beginning with http:// in separate lines in my opinion. I am sure one can get a list of Internet radio stations somewhere and use this feature very nicely. Hope this helps someone.