# Can't get pandora plugin for rhythmbox 2.97 to work

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, pandora

I installed this repository and updated it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
```

And then installed the plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-complete
```

Everything seemed to install fine and most if not all (didn't check everyone) of the other plugins are in RhythmBox, but the Pandora one wont come up. I've also tried installing it from the `zip` with the `setup.sh` and still nothing in RhythmBox. Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA mentioned is actually mine.

It doesnt have a pandora plugin - I presume you are referring to this GitHub project:

- https://github.com/mzheng/rhythmbox-pandora

Unfortunately, this plugin as not been ported to GTK3 - thus it will not run on any version of Rhythmbox used in Ubuntu 11.10 and later.

Until someone takes on this task you will not have the ability to use Pandora radio via Rhythmbox.

---

Alternatives:

Rhythmbox itself has built in Radio capabilities - you can add radio stations manually.

My PPA has a plugin called *radio-browser* which allows you to browse various radio stations

- [How to integrate Rhythmbox to play Internet Radio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210688/how-to-integrate-rhythmbox-to-play-internet-radio/210726#210726)

There are alternative Pandora clients - such as [Pithos](http://kevinmehall.net/p/pithos/)

- https://github.com/kevinmehall/pithos

---

Taking up the challenge:

If you are a coder yourself, then the pandora plugin is written in Python.

You'll need a good guide such as the following to help you to recode this to GTK3 using GIO bindings.

- https://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/WritingGuide

Also, looking at GTK3 python ported code will help you to understand the new structures and API to use.

- https://github.com/fossfreedom/radio-browser

Comment: Ahh yeah I must of got the impression it was updated for 2.97 but thank you for pointing that out. Hopefully someone can code thatin the near future because that would be an amazing plugin for rhythm box. I downloaded pithos and checked it out and its alright for what it is  so I'll just stick with that till  theirs any news of a plug-in. Thank you again for your response, i appreciate it.