# Glitching and delayed output when recording PulseAudio loopback

Tags: pulseaudio

I try to make a screencast where I need to record both microphone and pc output sound (and video of course) . 
I tried to make a loopback in pulseaudio to "merge" them and using this sink with the recording tool (first i tried recordmydesktop then ffmpeg/avconv).

But the issue is when I use this loopback , the sound is glitching (I think this is the better word describing it) and have progressive delay (meaning a lot lot delay after 2/3 minutes). This is not happening when using direct output (mic or pc output).

I tried to reduce the delay of the loopback to 1ms , didn't change anything  (it didn't want 0ms)

Is there any way I can resolve this. I hear about realtime pulseaudio but i think this is a kind a cpu eater? (and we need a RT kernel wich I think I don't have)

I also try to install jackd but without great success (and apparently it's a pain in the ass to make it working with avconv).

Comment: You can [use the pulseaudio monitor interface](http://askubuntu.com/a/60856/668478). E.g. card_name.***monitor***.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a loopack sink with `pulseaudio-module-loopback` in most sound card harwares we have the possibility to merge a source with a sink by using a **duplex audio profile**.

To switch to a duplex profile we can run [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] to select the *"Analog Stereo Duplex"* profile for our soundcard in the *"Configuration"* tab.

[image]

---

We can also change sink output profile from the command line with `<index>` and possible `<profiles>` of cards listed with

```
pacmd list-cards
```

To change the card profile we may then issue

```
pacmd set-card-profile <index> <profile>
```

---

To combine output sinks we may run [paprefs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/paprefs) [image: Install paprefs] which give us an option for a *"Simultaneous output device"*:

[image]

This combined device can also be loaded from the command line by loading the module [module-combine-sink](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-combine-sink).

Comment: I did succeed to add the virtual output , but i can't get the mic input in it (i can only redirect application that plays sound to the simultaneous output). I missing something ?

Comment: @eephyne: did you manage to choose a duplex profile?

Comment: yes i selected it via pavucontrol and pacmd said: active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>

Comment: @eephyne: just a guess: are any microphone or capture devices muted? See with `alsamixer`, or with `pacmd list-sinks`.

Comment: I don't think since I can record microphone (computer not on right now can't check this out).

Answer (score 1):

Duplex means the card acts as both an input and an output device for audio. It does not mean that it simply combines the output and the input into a single stream. And all the virtual output does is combine the sinks like you said, so that you can output from two separate cards at once. Neither of these accomplish what the OP, and myself, are trying to do.