# Noise removal from USB soundcard

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, noise

I am using the Syba USB soundcard for live audio from other audio sources like bluetooth or logitech mic. It's working perfectly, I am able to hear the live audio of bluetooth and logitech from the USB soundcard.

But the audio coming into the soundcard is not clear there is too much noise with the audio.

The USB soundcard has two port one for speaker and another for mic. When I hear the audio without plugin the headphone into speaker only plugin the headphne to mic then the noise is not coming.

But if I plugin the headphone in speaker port the noise coming is startrd.

Can I remove or control the noise coming into the soundcard.?

I am Using the following ffmpeg command for recording:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f v4l2 -s 544x288 -i /dev/video0 -vstats -vstats_file '/home/video-output//2014-05-13T07-18-37/left_cam-stats' -f pulse -name 'Unknown source 0' -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo -filter lowpass -f pulse -name 'left_mic 0' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'right_mic 1' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'default 0' -i default  -f mpegts -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -t 02:00:00 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 -map 4:0 /home/left_cam.mp4
```

Comment: @Takkat -The noise coming is very horrible, Is there any way to stop all types of noise?

Comment: @Takkat -isn't possible to reduce the noise?

Comment: @Takkat -  I thinks it is feed back noise. Also I have edited question. Can you please look it once

Comment: Nice edit! Had you set up a "duplex" profile? If yes, you may have to disable it. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/94854/how-do-i-turn-off-audio-echo-from-microphone-to-local-speakers, http://askubuntu.com/questions/291910/how-to-capture-desktop-sounds-pulse-audio-output-from-avconv, http://askubuntu.com/questions/240263/glitching-and-delayed-output-when-recording-pulseaudio-loopback

Comment: @Takkat - Can we disable duplex profile from command. b'coz this issue causing system is access on my machine, so I have to made the duplex profile disable using command. Also is there any command for this? please tell me

Comment: See [my answer there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240263/glitching-and-delayed-output-when-recording-pulseaudio-loopback). You may want profile `output:analog-stereo` depending on your card's available profiles (shown with `pacmd list-cards`)