# Pulseaudio loopback unload audio output devices

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm trying to find out how to unload pulseaudio loopback outputs. I'm using pulseaudio to create a loopback mix to capture my microphone and system audio for streaming. Every time I launch my script which has this code:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=mix 
pactl load-module module-loopback sink=mix
pactl load-module module-loopback sink=mix

avconv ...

pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

it leaves two output devices behind after it closes. The unload-module command gets rid of the recording one but I can't find a command for the outputs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### The appropriate way to unload modules

Unloading a module loaded to Pulse Audio is done by the module's index number, which is given on loading:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=test
24
```

In the above example Pulseaudio server loaded the module with index id `24`. This module can be unloaded with the following command:

```
pactl unload-module 24
```

Your script will have to parse the output of `pactl`.

In case we do not know the module number we can issue the following command which will display the number and the module name:

```
pactl list short modules
```

Newer versions also allow unloading by name:

```
pactl unload-module <name>
```

---

#### The quick and dirty method

If pulseaudio is set up as auto-spawning demon (which should be the default begaviour) we may quickly unload all modules loaded after login with a reset of the PulseAudio server to load the default modules defined in our `default.pa` by running:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

This will effectively unload all modules from your script and will load the default sink for output.

Comment: Worth mentioning that not all aplications will recover from having their streams cut.

Comment: Get the module number by sink name: `MODULE_NUMBER=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep -E "^\s*name:|^\s*module:" | grep -A 1 -E "^\s*name: <MY-SINK-NAME>" | grep -oP "module: \K[0-9]+")` where `MY-SINK-NAME` is what it says. Keep the `<` `>` in the code!

Comment: @KrisWebDev: thanks, added a line on how to get module indices for a more general aproach.

Comment: Great, then this becomes: `pactl list short modules | grep "sink_name=MY-SINK-NAME" | cut -f1 | xargs -L1 pactl unload-module`. It has the advantage of deleting ALL modules named `MY-SINK-NAME` (sink names are not unique).