# Can a Mumble Server be hosted on a Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: server, voip, mumble

I am running Kubuntu 15.04 and I want to run my own Mumble Server. Is it possible to do off of the desktop or do you need to be running a Ubuntu server? I have tried setting it up via `sudo apt-get install mumble-server`
and setting it up via `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mumble-server` then editing the .ini file and thought I would be good to go but alas, Connection Denied. I must be doing something wrong I am sure, I am totally new to setting up any kind of voice server. Any help would be appreciated or a kick in the direction of something along the lines of setting up Murmur for dummies as I couldn't find anything tailored towards a complete noob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem running it on the Desktop version, although you may have issues if you don't have a static IP address. Have you tried following the [Murmur Guide](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Murmurguide)? Do you have a firewall like UFW or IPtables active? Also, have you tried looking through the log at `/var/log/mumble-server/mumble-server.log` to see what the error is exactly (you'll need to do this as root)?

Comment: I had no firewall on at the time, but I did not set a static IP to start off with so I guess I need to try that and look through the logs. Thanks for the info and I'll post my findings!

Comment: @TheSchwa That worked! I didn't think that would make a difference just for at-the-moment testing, or maybe I did something stupid and did not realize it, but I went back and set it back up and it is running perfectly! Thanks for the response, and slapping some sense into me.

Comment: So I was testing the server and I, and other users, can log in fine. Everyone else can talk and hear each other, although I can not be heard. I can hear everyone just fine but when I try to speak they can not hear me, the lip icon lights up and all my audio output settings are set up correctly in my Mumble client settings. Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this? Thanks again for any info.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now `:)` I posted it as an answer, please accept it when you get a chance. You should post the mic problem as a new question, but in the meantime I'd try listening to the mic to make sure you can hear youself. Either record yourself with a program like `audacity` and play back the audio, or enable loopback as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/262297/205638) (use headphones!) and after testing, disable it as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/355539/205638).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely be able to run a Mumble server on Ubuntu Desktop, although you may need to account for not having a static IP depending on your setup.

Try using the [official Murmur Guide](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Murmurguide) to set up the server. Also make sure you open the appropriate port for both UDP and TCP (default 64738) in your firewall if you have one.