# Recording audio to a pulseaudio stream / sink input, and playing from stream on demand

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, streaming

I am using CS42888 codec in order to record audio from Line Input. I read the thread [Record a program's output with PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio) and got some ideas towards what I am trying to achieve. However, I have a few problems.

**Problem**

Firstly, the only way I'm able to record from the device currently is as follows:

```
arecord -Dhw:cs42888audio -f S16_LE -r 48000 test.wav
```

I can play with:

```
arecord -Dhw:cs42888audio test.wav
```

I would like to introduce the following:

- Record the cs42888audio input to a pulseaudio stream (under "radio" name)

Either:

- Whenever "radio" stream is available, I would like to make that my default stream and route it to cs42888 output.

Or:

- Always record to "radio" stream on background. Play/stream it whenever needed with a set of commands.

**What I've Tried**

```
pactl list sink-inputs                         # Gives nothing
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=radio
pactl move-sink-input 3 radio                  # Fails
parec --format=s16le --rate=48000 -d alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51.monitor | lame -r --quiet -q 3 --lowpass 17 --abr 192 - "temp.mp3"
aplay -Dhw:cs42888audio temp.mp3               # No audio other than noise
```

**Sound Configuration**

My .asoundrc is as follows:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
    device 0
}
```

My /etc/pulse/system.pa has:

```
set-default-source alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono
set-default-sink alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono
```

aplay -l gives:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 0: HiFi cs42888-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 0: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 1: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord -l gives:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 0: HiFi cs42888-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 0: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

pactl list short sinks

```
0   alsa_output.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 6ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

pactl list short sources

```
0   alsa_output.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_input.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 6ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Guidance is greately appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-mono sink=alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51 rate=48000
```

However,
`pactl unload-module module-loopback` does not work effectively, waits for a few seconds. It would be good if I could unload it instantly.